# How do I access a website if it apparently uses an insecure connection?

Tags: facebook

I've always been able to access facebook on my laptop, although for the past 24 hours when I've tried to access facebook it comes up with insecure connection, I've tried using both google chrome and internet explorer but neither works. I also looked on internet explorer help but it said it isn't possible to do anything about it. Is there any way of being able to access facebook if it is suddenly an insecure connection?

Comment: https://facebook.com What is more important - they have HSTS set, so if you see something like that it means that whoever provides you connection - intentionally want you to go through insecure connection to capture your traffic. So it's either a malicious software on your PC/router or maliciously curious Internet Provider.

Answer (score 1):

First, check your laptop's clock if it is set to the correct time and date. If not, correct it and check if you can access Facebook.

If the date is ok, then check the following stuff:

- Are you using your laptop from a new location such as a public hot spot? If yes, then the hot spot is probably compromised and you should try it again from a private network
- Run some antivirus software. Your laptop could be infected by some kind of malware.

Answer (score 0):

I agree I've seen this before with time and date not correct. Ssl Certs require correct time and date at the browser to function.